# AWS Access Keys Work Local Host but Not Depoloyment

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am pretty lost here... I can use my AWS S3 Bucket on my localhost/ local server but not deployment on Heroku. I have tried a ton of searches and different approaches - Can anyone help?

Basically... I have configured the Access Key ID through the IAM User. I also tried the Global Access Key ID and Secret Key Id.

I am getting the error:

```
error InvalidAccessKeyId: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
```

Thanks!

Here is my config in the server file -

```
    // config for AWS bucket and rekognition services
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: process.env.KEY,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.SECRET,
  region: "us-east-2",
});

const s3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01'})
const AWSParameters = {
    "accessKeyId": process.env.KEY,
    "secretAccessKey": process.env.SECRET,
    "region": "us-east-2",
    "bucket": "dk-prototype",
    "ACL": "public-read"
}

const rekognition = new AWS.Rekognition(AWSParameters);
const ses = new AWS.SES(AWSParameters);
```

Here is the POST request --

```
    app.post ('/upload-card-front/:game/:owner', isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
  let ts = Date.now();
  let current_userID = res.locals.user.id;
  let current_user_screen_name = req.params.owner;
  let current_user_profile_pic = res.locals.user.picture;
  let key = current_userID + ts;
  var game = req.params.game
  s3.upload({
      Bucket: 'dk-prototype',
      Key:  `${key}.png`,
      Body: req.files.card_front.data,
      ACL: 'public-read',
    }, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('error', err)
      }
        var params = {
          Image: {
            S3Object: {
              Bucket: 'dk-prototype',
              Name: `${key}.png`,
            }
          }
        };
        rekognition.detectText(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err, err.stack);
        } else {
          var name = ''
          if(game == 'Magic the Gathering'){
            name = data['TextDetections'][0]['DetectedText'];
          } else if(game == 'Pokemon'){
            name = data['TextDetections'][1]['DetectedText'].split(' ')[0];
          } else if(game == 'yugioh'){
            let name_length = data['TextDetections'][0]['DetectedText'].length;
            let raw_name = data['TextDetections'][0]['DetectedText'];
            let to_parse = raw_name.toUpperCase().split(' ', 3);
            to_parse.forEach(function(val, i){
              if(i !== to_parse.length -1){
                name +=  val + ' '
              }
            })
          } else if(game == 'warcraft'){
            name = data['TextDetections'][0]['DetectedText'];
          } else {
            let vanguard_card = data['TextDetections']
            vanguard_card.forEach(function(c, i){
              if(i == vanguard_card.length - 4){
                name = c['DetectedText'];
              }
            });
          }
          var card = {
            game: game,
            name: name,
            front: `https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/dk-prototype/${key}.png`,
            user_id: current_userID,
            user_screen_name: current_user_screen_name,
            profile_pic: current_user_profile_pic
          }
          var q = "INSERT INTO user_cards VALUES (default, ${game}, ${name}, ${front}, ${user_id}, ${user_screen_name}, ${profile_pic}, default, default)";
          db.result(q, card)
            .then(function (result) {
            })
            .catch(function (e){
              console.log('error', e);
            });
          if(game == 'Magic the Gathering'){
            mtg_card = data['TextDetections'][0]['DetectedText'];
            var valid_card = false;
            mtg.card.all({ name: mtg_card })
              .on('data', card => {
                // mtg_card_data = card
                valid_card = true;
              });
          } else if(game == 'Pokemon') {
            console.log('let\'s hunt us one of them pokeman')
            pokemon_card = data['TextDetections'][1]['DetectedText'].split(' ')[0];
            console.log('here is your pokemon', pokemon_card)
            var valid_card = false;
            pokemon.card.all({ name: pokemon_card})
              .on('data', card => {
                  valid_card = true;
                });
          } else if(game == 'yugioh'){
            let api_url = `http://yugiohprices.com/api/card_data/${name}`;
            axios.get(api_url)
              .then(function(r){
                if(r.data.status == 'success'){
                valid_card = true;
                }
              })
              .catch(function(e){
                console.log(e);
              });
          } else if(game == 'warcraft'){
          // so far no working api for warcraft
          valid_card = true;
          } else {
          //so far no working api for vanguard
            valid_card = true;
          }
          setTimeout(function(){
            if (valid_card == true) {
              var q = `SELECT * FROM user_cards WHERE game = \'${game}\' and user_id = '${current_userID}' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`;
              db.result(q)
                .then(function(r) {
                    let front = r.rows[0].front
                    let validity = 'TRUE';
                    var q = `UPDATE user_cards SET valid = \'${validity}\' WHERE front = \'${front}\'`;
                    db.result(q)
                      .then(function (result) {
                      })
                  })
                  .catch(function(e){
                    console.log('error', e);
                  });
            }
          }, 2000);
        };
      });
    });
  res.redirect(`/games/card-back?name=back&game=${game}&owner=${current_user_screen_name}`);
});
```

Comment: That error message is saying that you have provided an invalid Access Key. You should debug your code to see what it is using.

Comment: Is there a certain way you would suggest that I debug this? Isn't it kind of weird that it works with that access key on the local server but not heroku?

Comment: Alright... it's resolved... I am dumb is the answer! I had forgotten to update the heroku config file with the correct variable. -- Thanks for taking your time!